# Android - How to get Uri from raw file?

Tags: java, android, uri, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to get the `Uri` from a raw file I have included in the project in the `raw` folder.
But I am getting a `FileNotFoundException`, no matter what.

The file is a `.wav` file, also tried it with a `.mp4`, also doesn't work.
Playing both files with `MediaPlayer` DOES work.

The `Uri` returns: `mark.dijkema.android.eindopdracht/2130968576`

My Code:

```
package mark.dijkema.android.eindopdracht;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PlayWaveFile();
    }

    private void PlayWaveFile()
    {
        // define the buffer size for audio track
        int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        int bufferSize = 512;
        AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        Uri url = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.usa_for_africa_we_are_the_world);
        File file = new File(url.toString());

        int count = 0;
        byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(fileInputStream);
            audioTrack.play();

            while((count = dataInputStream.read(data, 0, bufferSize)) > -1)
            {
                audioTrack.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            audioTrack.stop();
            audioTrack.release();
            dataInputStream.close();
            fileInputStream.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The Error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mark.dijkema.android.eindopdracht/2130968576: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this approach, use `getResources().openRawResource(ResourceID)` as your inputStream.
Somewhere along this :

```
//FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
InputStream inputStream  = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.usa_for_africa_we_are_the_world);
DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
audioTrack.play();
```

`getResources().openRawResource(ResourceID)` returns an InputStream

EDIT : Remove these code if you use the above approach

```
Uri url = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.usa_for_africa_we_are_the_world);
File file = new File(url.toString());
```

Hope this helps, Good Luck! ^^

Comment: Yes, it now works. Need to fix the audio though, lot of noise in it and stuff.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
uri = Uri.parse(
                ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                        + File.pathSeparator + File.separator + File.separator
                        + context.getPackageName()
                        + File.separator
                        + R.raw.myrawname
        );
```

Comment: Does this even work? When I use this on Android's media player I get (No such file or directory).

Answer (score 9):

Dont hardcode stuff in code! Use this:

```
val uri = Uri.Builder()
    .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
    .authority(packageName)
    .appendPath("${R.raw.your_music_file_or_whatever}")
    .build()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are some methods that might help someone:

```
    public Uri getRawUri(String filename) {
        return Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + File.pathSeparator + File.separator + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + filename);
    }
    public Uri getDrawableUri(String filename) {
        return Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + File.pathSeparator + File.separator + getPackageName() + "/drawable/" + filename);
    }
    public Uri getMipmapUri(String filename) {
        return Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + File.pathSeparator + File.separator + getPackageName() + "/mipmap/" + filename);
    }
```

Just call the method like this:

```
Uri rawUri = getRawUri("myFile.filetype");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can open your InputStream to the raw Resource like this:

```
InputStream rawInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.usa_for_africa_we_are_the_world)
DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(rawInputStream);
```

Comment: how is that a URI?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated answer for the latest Android SDK (currently 34).

To get the raw resource's URI:

```
val uri = Uri.Builder()
  .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
  .path(R.raw.audiofile.toString())
  .build()
```