# Issue setting a ringtone

Tags: android, ringtone

In one of my apps, I want to add the possibility for the user to set a ringtone with a sound from my res/raw folder.
As I had no idea about how to do it, I found a piece of code on this website.
I created clone of my project and I want to test this piece of code before adapting it to my app.
here is the code :

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "/myRingtonFolder/Audio/");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/myRingtonFolder/Audio/";

            File f = new File(path + "/"+ name + ".mp3");

            Uri mUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                    + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + name);
            ContentResolver mCr = context.getContentResolver();
            AssetFileDescriptor soundFile;
            try {
                soundFile = mCr.openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                soundFile = null;
            }

            try {
                byte[] readData = new byte[1024];
                FileInputStream fis = soundFile.createInputStream();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                int i = fis.read(readData);

                while (i != -1) {
                    fos.write(readData, 0, i);
                    i = fis.read(readData);
                }

                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException io) {
            }
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, f.getAbsolutePath());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, name);
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, f.length());
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);

            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(f
                    .getAbsolutePath());
            Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values); //errror here

            try {
                RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,
                        RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
                Settings.System.putString(mCr, Settings.System.RINGTONE,
                        newUri.toString());
            } catch (Throwable t) {

            }
```

The problem is I get this error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.mtoy.tiboxinshape, PID: 27721
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileInputStream android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor.createInputStream()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.mtoy.tiboxinshape.SoundAdaptateur$2.onLongClick(SoundAdaptateur.java:117)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:5243)
                                                                           at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:9225)
                                                                           at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:21127)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I know that the problem come from this line : `Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);`. I tried to add the permission in my manifest but I still get this error.
Can you help me to find the problem please.

Comment: Seems to be caused by a null `soundFile`.  Try the approach here in getting the raw resource - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791439/android-how-to-get-uri-from-raw-file (In any case, you should quit the method when you catch FileNotFoundException, as a null `soundFile` will cause null pointer exception otherwise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the 23 android version you need to ask the authorisation in the code and not only in the manifest.xml. Everything is explained here :
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html