# Reading a file from Raw folder is giving File not found exception

Tags: android

I am trying to read the file `dev.txt` from the Raw folder

**I have place the file:**

[image]

---

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + File.pathSeparator + File.separator + CaringApp.getAppInstance().getPackageName() + "/raw/" + "dev.txt");
PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(uri.getPath()));
```

**I am getting the exception:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /com.appname.organizer/raw/dev: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

**at line:**

```
PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(uri.getPath()));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37589716/7666442 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/16791630/7666442

Comment: That is same as the code I have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to read the file dev.txt from the Raw folder

That is a file on your development machine. It is not a file on the Android device. `FileReader` will not work.

Instead, use `openRawResource()` on a `Resources` object to get an `InputStream`. If needed, wrap that in an `InputStreamReader`.

Answer (score 0):

In my app, I have used this and it is working for me :

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/assets/dev.txt");
File f = new File(url.toURI());
```

Or you can directly get the input stream using getResourceAsStream() method :

```
InputStream  is= getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/levels.txt");
isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to **remove** the extension to the filename. E.g. "dev" not "dev.txt" Like :

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + File.pathSeparator + File.separator + CaringApp.getAppInstance().getPackageName() + "/raw/" + "dev");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this function to copy a binary from raw to app files dir, and execute the binary from there.

```
    File dev = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "dev.txt");

        if (!dev.exists()) {
            try {
                dev.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create new file!", e);
            }
        installBinaryFromRaw(this, R.raw.dev, dev);
```

function to copy files from raw to /data/data//file/filename

```
    public static void installBinaryFromRaw(Context context, int resId, File file) {
        final InputStream rawStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);
        final OutputStream binStream = getFileOutputStream(file);

        if (rawStream != null && binStream != null) {
            pipeStreams(rawStream, binStream);

            try {
                rawStream.close();
                binStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to close streams!", e);
            }

            doChmod(file, 755);
        }
    }
```